# Error Configuring application Listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

Tags: hibernate

// This is the error which I am facing severely when I am trying to run the Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse

```
**SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:927)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:298)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1626)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```